# list starts loading from the beginning after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter, onsaveinstancestate

In my fragment I have list. This list is is constantly filling. But after screen rotation list starts loading from the beginning. And the data that was in the vertical orientation is lost because in the horizontal orientation the list starts to load again. So, I added all what I could read in the internet:
in my Manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
```

in Activity class:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            firstFragment = FirstFragment()
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frameLayout, firstFragment!!, "firstFragment")
                .commit()
        } else {
            firstFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag("firstFragment") as? FirstFragment
        }
```

but it did not help.

Comment: try using [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQiA9P__BRC0ARIsAEZ6irhs9OW0Lxva5YiFU6wPMQxRbBikflfYtrHL0cdA_ppD6FobQOb1ohQaAnQ4EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: yes, I know that this can fix the problem. But I need do it without `ViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set `setRetainInstance(true);` in fragment code.

It will prevent recreating fragment instance.

Comment: [`setRetainInstance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)) is deprecated now .. Although this will solve the problem now, in the future this won't work any more .. you should rely on `ViewModels` instead